# Keep hover class if previously clicked element and mouse moving

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the `square` to be (and stay) `red` if I have previously clicked it and keep moving the mouse cursor into it.

```js
var pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
  pq;

pb.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.button == 0) {
    pb.classList.add('hover');
    pq = setTimeout(function() {
      pb.classList.remove('hover')
    }, 900)
  }
});

pb.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  clearTimeout(pq);
  pq = setTimeout(function() {
    pb.classList.remove('hover')
  }, 900)
});
```

```css
#pb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#pb.hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="pb"></div>
```

The issue I have is while I move the mouse cursor in the square, it goes back to `green`, and I don't expect this since I (should?) `clear` the `timeout` at each `mousemove` event.

What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove code which removes `hover` class after mouse clicked and use mouseout event instead of mousemove. See below code

```
var pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
pq;

pb.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  if (e.button == 0) {
   pb.classList.add('hover');
  }
});

pb.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
  clearTimeout(pq);
  pq = setTimeout(function () {
    pb.classList.remove('hover');
  }, 900)
});
```

**[JFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g603bkm2/)**